# Checking if dragged div is in right place

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I want to check if image is in right place after drop. It alerts "wrong" all the time. Dunno why.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<img id="drag1" src="img/patternslowo1.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
<img id="drag2" src="img/patternslowo2.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
<img id="drag3" src="img/patternslowo3.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
<img id="drag4" src="img/patternslowo4.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
<img id="drag5" src="img/patternslowo5.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
```

**Javascript:**

```
function allowDrop(ev)
{
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("content",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
  ev.preventDefault();
  var image =ev.dataTransfer.getData("content");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(image));

  if (ev.dataTransfer.getData('div1') == 'drag1'){ 
     alert("ok");
  }
  else{
     alert("wrong");
  }
}
```

Few hours trying to fix it and nothing.

You can check example on [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/ruddog2003/YbM2X/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking the wrong data in the `getData`.

You set `content` data on drag, but check `div1` on drop.

Your code must be:

```
function allowDrop(ev)
{
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("content",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
  ev.preventDefault();
  var image =ev.dataTransfer.getData("content");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(image));
  if (ev.dataTransfer.getData('content') == 'drag1'){ 
     alert("ok");
  }
  else{
     alert("wrong");
  }
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YbM2X/1/

### EDIT

You need to handle a relation between the dragged img and the dropped element.

I use the data-attribute `data-div` on the imgs to set a custom tag to handle this relation, on drop I ensure that the link is correct using [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getAttribute).

HTML:

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<img id="drag1" data-div="div1" src="http://images.stockfreeimages.com/866/sfi/free_8660001.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
<img id="drag2" data-div="div2" src="http://images.stockfreeimages.com/866/sfi/free_8660001.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
<img id="drag3"  data-div="div3" src="http://images.stockfreeimages.com/866/sfi/free_8660001.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
<img id="drag4"  data-div="div4" src="http://images.stockfreeimages.com/866/sfi/free_8660001.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
<img id="drag5"  data-div="div5" src="http://images.stockfreeimages.com/866/sfi/free_8660001.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
```

Code:

```
function allowDrop(ev)
{
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("content",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
  ev.preventDefault();
        var image =ev.dataTransfer.getData("content");
  if (ev.target.id == document.getElementById(image).getAttribute('data-div')){ 
     alert("ok");          
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(image));
  }
  else{
     alert("wrong");
  }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YbM2X/4/

Comment: I want to match div1 with drag1, div2 with drag2, div3 with drag3. Your code checks if drag1 is on any div only. It should be if div1 == drag1, but I don't know how to write it.